# How to remove one line char(White space) from string

Tags: c#, string, whitespace

I want to remove a white space(\n) from a string but the below code is not working

```
var store_tran2 = "1220 3rd St ,                      Santa Monica,                                      CA 90401";
var store_tran1 = Trim(store_tran2);

Console.Write(store_tran1);
```

How to remove the one line char or white spaces?

Expected output:

```
1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var store_tran1  = Regex.Replace(store_tran2, " {2,}", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
string res =
    Regex.Replace(original, @"^\s*$\n", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline)
         .TrimEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `string.Replace` 
Your code be like this

```
var store_tran2 = "1220 3rd St ,                      Santa Monica,                                      CA 90401";
var store_tran1 = store_tran2.Replace("  ",string.Empty);
```

Your output  shoould be like

```
1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica,CA 90401
```

**Note**

> Put two spaces inside quotes "  ".

Answer (score 0):

```
store_tran2 = store_tran2.Replace("\n","").Replace(" ","");
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers works very good may be eaxct fit for the question

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381525/removing-white-spaces-from-string-is-not-working-in-c-sharp/37381559#37381559
```