# Removing White spaces from string is not working in c#

Tags: c#, trim

I am trying to remove whitespaces from string but it is not working

```
string status = "                                       18820 Pacific Coast Highway

                                        Malibu, CA 90265";
        string status1 = status.Trim();
        Console.Write(status1);
```

The above code is not working

Expected Output:

```
18820 Pacific Coast Highway Malibu, CA 90265
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? What is the output?

Comment: It seems to be working. `.Trim()` does not remove ALL whitespaces. it removes "extra" whitespaces. see examples here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381952/how-automatically-remove-all-white-spaces-start-or-end-in-a-string?answertab=active#tab-top ..  Also, If you want to remove ALL of them, use the `.Replace()` method like this:  `status.Replace(" ", "");`

Comment: try to use replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Trim()` only works at the start and end of a string.  This should work:

```
string status1 = Regex.Replace(status,@"\s+"," ").Trim();
```

Comment: a better flag option is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c

Answer (score 4):

Trim removes leading and trailing symbols (spaces by default). Use Regular expression instead.

```
RegEx.Replace(status, "\s+", " ").Trim();
```

Comment: a better flag option is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c

Answer (score -1):

```
string status = "                                       18820 Pacific Coast Highway

                                        Malibu, CA 90265";
        string status1 = status.Trim();
        Console.Write(status1);


status = status .Replace(" ", "");
```

But the above code will remove all the whitespaces.

If you want to have whitespace at the end of everyword, then use foreach as mentioned in this link

[How to trim whitespace between characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905180/how-to-trim-whitespace-between-characters)

Comment: Doesn't work - did you try it? It halves the number of spaces each time.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.